# How can I get a list of custom post IDs into a variable I can use for another function?

Tags: array

How can I get the same output into a variable that I can then use in another function?

```
//get all the post ids of current projects
$qry_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish', // optional
        'post_type' => 'project', // 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // ALL posts
        'fields' => 'ids',
        );

    $all_posts = new WP_Query( $qry_args );
    foreach((array) $all_posts->posts as $id) {
        echo $id .',';
    }
```

The above code works fine to create an "array" of IDs, but I need to be able to put it into a variable so I can then use it in another function like so:

```
echo do_shortcode('[mla_gallery post_parent='.  $ARRAYOFid .' posts_per_page=12]');
```

I know I am missing something easy here...

Comment: I dont think `post_parent` accepts array. It should be an ID.

Comment: @Roberthue You are correct. Doh!  Good thing is that I did find a way to accomplish this.  Going to post answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push all your individual id's from your `foreach`  loop to a variable outside your `foreach` loop, like this (*please note, this is not the preferred method as there is a simpler method, just scroll down*)

```
$post_ids = [];
foreach((array) $all_posts->posts as $id) {
   $post_ids[] = $id;
}
?><pre><?php var_dump($post_ids); ?></pre><?php
```

`$post_ids` will hold your array of id's

Alternatively, which is actually the better and preferred method here, `$all_posts->posts` already holds an array of post ids, just assign that to a variable

```
$post_ids = $all_posts->posts; 
?><pre><?php var_dump($post_ids ); ?></pre><?php
```

**EDIT**

If you need a string of id's, you can just implode `$post_ids`

```
$string_ids = implode( ',', $post_ids );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Pieter Goosen's tip, I was able to get this working. In case anyone else is following or for future reference, I have gone a bit further with this code so that now I am creating an array of the thumbnail IDs for all related posts by category in custom taxonomy. I am then passing this array to the mla_gallery shortcode to dynamically call a list of related projects with thumbnails that link to the parent page. 
Demo: http://ecominded.wpengine.com/landscape-design-construction/landscape-construction/

```
//get all the post ids of current projects

  $post = get_post( $post->ID );//get current post
   // get the terms related to post
   $args = array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'slugs');
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'project_category' , $args);

$qry_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish', // optional
        'post_type' => 'project', // Change to match your post_type
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'project_category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $terms,
                ),
            ),  
        'posts_per_page' => 12, // # of posts
        'fields' => 'ids',
        );

    $all_posts = new WP_Query( $qry_args );
    $post_thumbnail_ids = array();//initialize array

    foreach((array) $all_posts->posts as $id) {
        $post_thumbnail_ids[] = get_post_thumbnail_id( $id );
    }

    $string_ids = implode( ',', $post_thumbnail_ids );//convert to string for shortcode


echo do_shortcode('[mla_gallery post_parent=any posts_per_page=12 ids='.  $string_ids .' ]'); 

echo do_shortcode('[mla_gallery  post_parent=any posts_per_page=12 ids='.  $string_ids .'  mla_output=paginate_links]');
```